# ofInstant is not a member of object java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, java-time, java.time.instant

I have following scala code:

```
LocalDate.ofInstant(instant, zoneId)
```

instant is java.time.Instant, zoneId is java.time.ZoneId.

Intellij project is configured to jdk 17 and language level to 15.

But I get error:

```
value ofInstant is not a member of object java.time.LocalDate
```

I am unable to find why. Java versions are correct one I think.

Comment: Given that the method [exists](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~cs272/javadoc/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofInstant(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)) and that you mention that is **IntelliJ** the one mentioning the error I will just assume is a bug in the IDE, can you confirm that if you try to compile using **sbt** or whatever build tool you are using the problem remains?

Comment: That `ofInstant` exists since java 9. Which leads me to believe you are using java 8 despite java 17.

Comment: I have configured project to jdk 17.

Comment: I compile with 'sbt clean compile' command.

Comment: No local variable.

Comment: Ah then maybe is the default of the `target` option? Try adding this to your `build.sbt` file : `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-release", "17", "-target:17")` _(change `17` with the minimum version of the **JRE** you want to support)_

Comment: but as I have configured my intellij project to jdk 17,  sbt server must target 17.

Comment: @Mandroid _"sbt server must target 17"_ yes, **sbt** will be running on top of a **Java** `17` VM, however that doesn't mean it will default to produce **Java 17** bytecode. IIRC **Scala** by default always produces **Java 8** bytecode, the flags I shared are to configure and force the compiler to produce the bytecode version you want; why don't you give it a try?

Comment: I actually tried it, but I still see very same issue.

Comment: @Mandroid sorry, I can't reproduce the issue, it seems that even without configuring **sbt** it is able to compile that code because my **JDK** is `openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19`, thus it seems you have some problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 to get LocalDate from Instant you can do as follows

```
 LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```